# How to add data to HTML for javascript to use

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dynamically created page with repeated elements, like so:

```
<input type="file" name="file1">
<input type="file" name="file2">
<input type="file" name="file3">
```

I would like to add some data to each of these elements for use in JavaScript. Originally I used "spare" attributes that while valid on an input tag were not valid on a file type input tag, eg, `size`. I have now added it to the class attribute, but have to use a `regex` to get it out again. Neither of these methods seem very satisfactory, is there a better way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Yep, you can use jQuery and it's `attr` property to get/set what you need, http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite often I see data added through attributes that are prefixed with `data-`, for instance:

```
<input type="file" name="file1" data-filesize="871">
```

jQuery even has function to conveniently read that information, for instance like this:

```
var filesize = $('input[name="file1"]').data('filesize');
```

And, to write the data, attr can be used:

```
$('input[name="file1"]').attr("data-filesize", filesize );
```

See also: [HTML 5 data atributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use attributes with a name starting with "data-"

Answer (score 1):

Use the data attribute: `<input data-something="somevalue" />`

Answer (score 0):

with attribute start with `data-` you can use your own other name appending to it.

[Go through this examples](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)